# Show that $\exists x \in (0, \pi/2)$ such that $\cos(x)=x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x) = \cos(x)$, $g(x)=x$, both functions are continuous. $f(0)=1$, $f(\pi/2)=0$, so, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, for any $z\in [0,1]$, there exists $c\in [0,\pi/2]$ such that $f(x)=z$.

This should be simple to prove, but for some reason I have a problem with IVT, don't know why. Would appreciate some help.

I think that the fact that $g(x)=x$ is onto $[0,1]\subset [0, \pi/2]$ should be used here somehow.

Comment: Subtract them, then IVT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $h(x)=\cos(x)-x$. Then, $h(0)=1$ and $h\left( \displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence, $h(0)>h\left( \displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and, clearly, $h(x)$ is continuous. For the IVT, there exist a $z\in\left( 0,\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ such that $h(z)=0$.

$h(z)=0$ if and only if $\cos(z)-z=0$ if and only if $\cos(z)=z$

Comment: You could also use $h(1)=\cos(1)-1<1-1=0$ to get the argument working on the smaller interval.

Answer (score 4):

If a solution for $\cos(x) = x$ exists in $[0, \pi/2]$, it must lie somewhere in the interval $[0, 1]$ as $\cos(x)$ is bounded above by $1$.  If we can show that $\cos:[0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$ is a [contraction mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping), then the [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) guarantees a fixed point on this interval—that is, a point where $\cos(x) = x$.  By definition, it is a contraction mapping if there exists a $q \in [0, 1)$ such that $|\cos(x) - \cos(y)| \leq q|x-y|$ for all $x, y \in [0, 1]$.

Rearranging this yields $\displaystyle \frac{|\cos(x) - \cos(y)|}{|x-y|} \leq q$.  How large can the left hand side get? The [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) tells us the left hand side will be bounded by the absolute value of the largest possible  evaluation of cosine's derivative on $[0, 1]$.  We have $\displaystyle \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{dx}} \cos(x) = -\sin(x)$.  Because $\sin(0) = 0$, and because $\sin$ is strictly increasing on $[0, \pi/2]$, we can safely conclude that the left hand side of the above inequality is bounded above by $\sin(1)$.  Since $0 < \sin(1) < \sin(\pi/2) = 1$, this value can serve as our $q$.

Therefore, cosine on the interval $[0,1]$ is a contraction mapping $\implies$ a fixed point is guaranteed by the Banach fixed-point theorem.

Comment: An advanced answer for an elementary question, nevertheless great

Answer (score 1):

Define $h(x)=\cos x-x$

Then $h(0)=1>0;h(\frac{\pi}{2})=-\frac{\pi}{2}<0$

By IVP $\exists c\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ such that $h(c)=0$

Answer (score -3):

The proof is immediate by the use of graphs of $y=\cos x$ and $y=x$ in the given interval. See this [Wolfram Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3Dcos%28x%29+and+y%3Dx&x=9&y=14&js=off) link for plots