# How do I use the intermediate value theorem to prove that $x=\cos x$ has a solution?

Tags: calculus

I'm taking differential calculus, and I've read that is actually a pretty interesting function that just has one solution. I'm a little confused since most proofs that involve the Intermediate value theorem give a closed interval. But I need to prove that it has a solution in the real numbers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $\exists x \in (0, \pi/2)$ such that $\cos(x)=x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019442/show-that-exists-x-in-0-pi-2-such-that-cosx-x)

Comment: If it has a solution in an interval of the real numbers, then that solution is in the real numbers

Comment: @MarkS. : You're mistaken: this is not a duplicate of the question you cite. You have to read carefully. The question does not ask how to show the equation has a solution in a specified interval. Read the sentence that refers to "most proofs".

Comment: @MichaelHardy I realized that (hence the answer I posted), but I did not know that I could retract close votes until just now.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Let $f(x)=x-\cos(x)$.

Note that $f$ is continuous  for $x\in[0,\pi/2]$ with $f(0)=-1$ and $f(\pi/2)=\pi/2$.

Given the Intermediate Value Theorem, what can one say about $f$ on the closed interval $[0,\pi/2]$, which is a subset of the real numbers?

Comment: I wonder if you realize what the question said. It said "I'm a little confused since most proofs that involve the Intermediate value theorem give a closed interval. But I need to prove that it has a solution in the real numbers." Your answer does not address that.

Comment: @michaelhardy  This post is just a hint.  But, it gives a closed interval, a subset of the reals, for which the IVT applies and for which it guarantees existence if a number for which $f=0$.  What have I missed?

Comment: See my answer. I didn't give any closed interval. Maybe you're putting the emphasis in the wrong place for the occasion.

Comment: @michaelhardy I edited to add that $[0,\pi]$ is a subset of the real numbers.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I haven't seen you for a while; nice to see you're back.  Where have you been hiding?

Answer (score 1):

I think I misread your question initially. It seems you're asking something like "I've seen proofs that there's a solution on a closed interval using the Intermediate Value Theorem, but how do you prove there's a solution in the reals?"

If that's your question, the answer is that a closed interval is contained within the reals (as a subset), so a solution "on a closed interval" *is* a solution in the real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a suitable closed interval within which there is a solution, then there is a solution somewhere in the real line because the closed interval is a subset of the real line.

Answer (score 1):

Let the function 
$f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by 
$$f(x) = x - \cos x \ \mbox{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
Then we note that $$ f^\prime (x) = 1 + \sin x \geq 0 \ \mbox{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}. $$
So $f$ is a non-decreasing function on every (finite) interval on the real line, and $f$ is a strictly increasing function on every finite interval on the real line which does not include the points $\frac{3\pi}{2} + 2n \pi$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ as its interior points.

Moreover, we see that $$ f(0) = -1 \ \mbox{ and } \ f\left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
So if $x$, $y$, and $z$ are any three real numbers such that $$x < 0 < y < \frac{\pi}{2} < z,$$ then we must have 
$$ f(x) < f(0) = -1 < f(y)  <  f\left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) = \frac{\pi}{2} <  f(z).$$
Finally, as $f$ is continuous everywhere on the real line, so we can assume that there is exactly one real number $p$ such that $f(p)=0$; in fact that real number $p$ is strictly between $0$ and $\pi/2$.